# Changing size of footnote symbols in titlesec-formatted chapter titles

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, fontsize, titlesec, footmisc

I am using `titlesec` to define the formatting of Chapter titles. At present, footnote symbols within these titles appear in the same format, but my author would like them to be somewhat smaller.

The `\titleformat` block looks like this:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
 {\LARGE\bfseries} % format of title
 {\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thechapter}} % chapter number
 {0em} % no additional space between number-box and title
 ...
```

Is there a command I can use within this block to specify the size of footnote symbols in the title itself (and nowhere else)?

I am using `footmisc` for footnotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least for the standard document classes (and also with the `footmisc` package loaded), footnote marks are typeset as superscripts which adjust to (and should be appropriate for) the font size in effect. If you nevertheless want somewhat smaller marks in chapter titles, you could add a `\scalebox` (from the `graphicx` package) to the definition of the kernel macro `\@makefnmark` and adjust the scale dependend on whether you're inside a chapter title or not.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newif\ifheading

\newcommand*{\fnmarkscale}{\ifheading 0.85 \else 1 \fi}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makefnmark}
    {\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\scalebox{\fnmarkscale}{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
 {\LARGE\bfseries} % format of title
 {\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thechapter}} % chapter number
 {0em} % no additional space between number-box and title
 {\headingtrue\LARGE}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\textheight 180pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

\chapter[A chapter title]{A chapter title with a footnote\footnote{First footnote.}}

Some text with a footnote.\footnote{Second footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image]