# Footnote in section header causes unwanted new line

Tags: sectioning, footnotes

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.

When I use the following to add a footnote to a section header

```
\section{Section Name}\footnote{Footnote text.}
\label{sec:SectionLabel}
```

I get the superscript for the footnote as a separate paragraph in the section.  When I try

```
\section{Section Name\protect\footnote{Footnote text.}}
\label{sec:SectionLabel}
```

I get a compile error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

which I don't get otherwise since it is a fairly small document (33 pages).

Edit:  The compilable latex code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Required to use \text
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % Use ulem with normal (as opposed to underlined) emphasis option

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{float} % Required for tables and figures in the multi-column environment - they need to be placed in specific locations with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text
\usepackage{paralist} % Used for the compactitem environment which makes bullet points with less space between them

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{ Title $\bullet$ \date{\today}} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % For number set symbols
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}    {10pt}\selectfont\textbf{Title}} % Article title

\author{
    \large
    \textsc{Name}\thanks{Thankee}\\[2mm] 
    \normalsize Address \\ Address, cont\\
    \vspace{-5mm}
}
\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

    \maketitle % Insert title

    \thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers


    \section{Section Name}\footnote{Footnote text.}
    \label{sec:SectionLabel}

\end{document}
```

Further edited to add version number

Comment: what document class are you using?  (a compilable example would help us a lot.)

Comment: Thanks, Barbara.  I have edited my question to include the compilable code.  The document class is "article".  Thanks,

Comment: I have version 2.9.  This is the latest version I could find. http://miktex.org/download  Was your footnote supertext on the same line as the title header?  Thanks,

Comment: `\section[Section Name]{Section Name\footnote{Whatever}}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Protecting `\footnote` is completely useless; it would work if you didn't load `titlesec`, but you'd get the footnote also in several places (the table of contents, for example, and page headings).

There are two solutions to the issue:

1. (best) ***never*** footnote a section title
2. use

   ```
   \section[Section Name]{Section Name\footnote{Whatever}}
   ```

Comment: Why should we never footnote a section title? Also, why does adding the "[Section Name]" part work? (without it the document fails to compile but I don't understand why)

Answer (score 0):

I created a short command to do as [@egreg suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229724/35825), avoiding [this problem with the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/how-to-hide-a-footnote-in-a-section-title-from-the-table-of-contents) and [keeping a normal font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68880/changing-size-of-footnote-symbols-in-titlesec-formatted-chapter-titles):

```
\newcommand{\headingwithfootnote}[2]{
    #1[#2]{#2{\textsuperscript{\normalsize\footnotemark}}}}

...

\headingwithfootnote{\section}{Chapter Title}
\footnotetext{The footnote text.}
```